# MacBook Pro 14-inch M1 Pro battery drain while sleeping

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, sleep-wake, apple-silicon, monterey

My new 14-inch MacBook Pro (M1 Chip macOS Monterey 12.0.1) uses a lot of battery during sleep mode. I have tried the following potential solution with no luck:

- Restarting the Mac
- Erasing the Mac
- Reinstalling the OS
- Unchecking `Power Nap` -> There is currently no `Power Nap` on M1 Macs with Monterey

Here's the information from the Battery Usage History:
[image]

The `pmset -g log | grep "Wake Requests"` shows the following output:

```
2021-12-07 17:46:54 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=917 wakeAt=2021-12-07 18:02:11 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 19:46:54 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=313817 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=466385 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 18:02:16 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1046 wakeAt=2021-12-07 18:19:42 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 20:02:16 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=312895 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=465463 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 18:19:47 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=990 wakeAt=2021-12-07 18:36:17 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.2Hours"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 20:19:47 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=311844 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=464412 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 18:36:22 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1054 wakeAt=2021-12-07 18:53:56 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.backupd-auto"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 20:36:22 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=310849 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=463417 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 18:54:01 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1049 wakeAt=2021-12-07 19:11:30 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 20:54:01 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=309790 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=462358 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 19:11:35 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1013 wakeAt=2021-12-07 19:28:28 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.ap.adprivacyd.reconcile"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 21:11:35 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=308736 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=461304 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 19:28:33 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1024 wakeAt=2021-12-07 19:45:37 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 21:28:33 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=307718 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=460286 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 19:45:42 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1051 wakeAt=2021-12-07 20:03:13 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.backupd-auto"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 21:45:42 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=306689 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=459257 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 20:03:18 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1046 wakeAt=2021-12-07 20:20:44 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 22:03:18 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=305633 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=458201 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 20:20:49 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1035 wakeAt=2021-12-07 20:38:04 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 22:20:49 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=304582 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=457150 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 20:38:09 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=947 wakeAt=2021-12-07 20:53:56 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.osanalytics.submissions.submit"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 22:38:09 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=303542 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=456110 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 20:54:01 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=959 wakeAt=2021-12-07 21:10:00 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.backupd-auto"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 22:54:01 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=302590 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=455158 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 21:10:05 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=933 wakeAt=2021-12-07 21:25:38 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.6Hours"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:10:05 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=301626 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=454194 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 21:25:43 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1078 wakeAt=2021-12-07 21:43:41 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:25:43 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=300688 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=453256 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 21:43:46 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=899 wakeAt=2021-12-07 21:58:45 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:43:46 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=299605 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=452173 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 21:58:50 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1010 wakeAt=2021-12-07 22:15:40 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.appstored.Sbsync"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:58:50 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=298702 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=451269 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 22:15:45 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=902 wakeAt=2021-12-07 22:30:47 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:15:45 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=297687 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=450254 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 22:19:56 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=904 wakeAt=2021-12-07 22:35:00 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.KeyValueService.Production.Private.sync"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:19:56 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=297436 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=450004 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 22:35:05 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=949 wakeAt=2021-12-07 22:50:54 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.2Hours"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:35:05 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=296526 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=449094 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 22:50:59 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=971 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:07:10 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.appstored.ArcadePostSummary"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:50:59 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=295573 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=448140 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 23:07:15 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1006 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:24:01 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.coreduet.sync.triggered"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:07:15 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=294597 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=447164 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 23:20:03 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1001 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:36:44 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:20:03 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=293828 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=446396 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 23:36:49 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1046 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:54:15 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:36:49 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=292823 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=445390 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 23:43:23 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=975 wakeAt=2021-12-07 23:59:38 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:43:23 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=292429 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=444997 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-07 23:44:13 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=956 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:00:09 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.KeyValueService.Production.Private.sync"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:44:13 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=292378 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=444946 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 00:00:14 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1012 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:17:06 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:00:14 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=291418 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=443985 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 00:04:21 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=989 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:20:50 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:04:21 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=291171 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=443739 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 00:06:57 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=906 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:22:03 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:06:57 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=291014 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=443582 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 00:22:10 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=899 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:37:09 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:22:08 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=290102 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=442669 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 00:37:16 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=895 wakeAt=2021-12-08 00:52:11 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.2Hours"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:37:14 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=289196 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=441764 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 00:52:18 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1054 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:09:52 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:52:16 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=288294 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=440862 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 01:09:59 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=908 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:25:07 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.backupd-auto"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 03:09:57 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=287232 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=439800 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 01:25:14 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=971 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:41:25 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 03:25:12 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=286318 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=438886 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 01:41:32 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1074 wakeAt=2021-12-08 01:59:26 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 03:41:30 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=285340 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=437908 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 01:59:33 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=899 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:14:32 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 03:59:31 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=284259 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=436827 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 02:14:39 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=955 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:30:34 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.MobileAccessoryUpdater.deviceIdleCheck"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 04:14:37 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=283353 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=435921 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 02:30:41 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1014 wakeAt=2021-12-08 02:47:35 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 04:30:39 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=282391 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=434959 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 02:47:42 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=986 wakeAt=2021-12-08 03:04:08 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.2Hours"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 04:47:40 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=281370 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=433938 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 03:04:15 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=897 wakeAt=2021-12-08 03:19:12 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 05:04:13 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=280377 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=432945 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 03:19:19 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=947 wakeAt=2021-12-08 03:35:05 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.6Hours"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 05:19:17 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=279473 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=432041 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 03:35:12 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1060 wakeAt=2021-12-08 03:52:52 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 05:35:10 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=278520 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=431088 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 03:52:59 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=920 wakeAt=2021-12-08 04:08:19 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 05:52:57 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=277453 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=430021 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 04:08:26 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=917 wakeAt=2021-12-08 04:23:43 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 06:08:24 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=276526 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=429094 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 04:23:50 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=997 wakeAt=2021-12-08 04:40:27 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.backupd-auto"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 06:23:48 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=275602 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=428170 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 04:40:34 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=991 wakeAt=2021-12-08 04:57:05 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 06:40:32 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=274598 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=427166 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 04:57:12 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=943 wakeAt=2021-12-08 05:12:55 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.2Hours"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 06:57:10 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=273600 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=426168 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 05:13:02 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=903 wakeAt=2021-12-08 05:28:05 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 07:13:00 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=272650 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=425218 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 05:28:12 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=997 wakeAt=2021-12-08 05:44:49 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.backupd-auto"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 07:28:10 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=271740 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=424308 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 05:44:56 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=946 wakeAt=2021-12-08 06:00:42 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 07:44:54 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=270736 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=423304 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 06:00:49 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=953 wakeAt=2021-12-08 06:16:42 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 08:00:47 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=269783 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=422351 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 06:16:49 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=979 wakeAt=2021-12-08 06:33:08 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 08:16:47 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=268823 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=421391 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 06:33:14 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1045 wakeAt=2021-12-08 06:50:39 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.backupd-auto"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 08:33:13 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=267837 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=420405 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 06:50:46 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=996 wakeAt=2021-12-08 07:07:22 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 08:50:44 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=266786 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=419354 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 07:07:29 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1059 wakeAt=2021-12-08 07:25:08 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.CoreAnalytics.2Hours"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 09:07:27 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=265783 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=418351 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 07:25:15 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=1010 wakeAt=2021-12-08 07:42:05 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7198 wakeAt=2021-12-08 09:25:13 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=264717 wakeAt=2021-12-11 08:57:12] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=417285 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]           
2021-12-08 07:33:47 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=dasd request=SleepService deltaSecs=915 wakeAt=2021-12-08 07:49:02 info="com.apple.dasd:0:com.apple.bluetoooth.CBMetrics"] [process=dasd request=TimerPlugin deltaSecs=915 wakeAt=2021-12-08 07:49:02 info="com.apple.dasd:501:com.apple.mediaanalysisd.photos.visualsearch"] [process=mDNSResponder request=Maintenance deltaSecs=7200 wakeAt=2021-12-08 09:33:47 info="upkeep wake"] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=416773 wakeAt=2021-12-13 03:20:00 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,496"]
```

**Update: More useful info:**

- The bluetooth was off
- The wifi was on, but not connected

Comment: Do you have any bluetooth devices connected?

Comment: No, no bluetooth devices were connected.

Comment: Can you disable Bluetooth on the Macbook then and see whether it changes things?

Comment: I just noticed the bluetooth was off the whole time. Updated the post with more info.

Comment: mine is draining from 100% to completely dead during the night, similar wake requests logs. You are lucky that you're loosing only 8%

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Screen Time and sleep/wake Mac? (System Preferences > Screen Time > Options > Turn Off) and (System Preferences > Battery > Schedule > Uncheck.)

If the problem persists after the above, go to Apple menu > About this Mac > System Report > Hardware > Power > Power Events. See which are the next scheduled events and, if it makes sense, disable them.

Comment: There's no "Power Events" in my System Report (Monterey).

Comment: @EightyEight Click on "Power" and scroll all the way to the bottom.